# AngularJs: Error with POST, PUT and DELETE rest call. "XMLHttpRequest cannot load Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500"

Tags: angularjs

AngularJs: Error with POST, PUT and DELETE rest call. "XMLHttpRequest cannot load Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500" however GET is working. This is browser specific. In safari it works, but not in chrome. Please give me some solutions.

My service:

```
var saffModuleServices = angular.module('saffModuleServices');


saffModuleServices.factory('applications', ['$http','$resource','$appConstants',
  function($http, $resource,$appConstants){
    $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    var applicationsEndPoint      = $appConstants.adminApiEndPoint + 'admin/systems/:id';
    return {
      getApplications : function(){
        return $resource(applicationsEndPoint , {}, {
          query: {method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: false},
              post: {method: 'POST', params: {}, isArray: false, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'}},
              update: {method: 'PUT', params: {}},
              delete :  {method: 'DELETE'}
        });
      }
    }

  }]);
```

function in controller:

```
$scope.save = function(){
      var modelSchema = {
        name : $scope.applicationsDetails.name,
        description : $scope.applicationsDetails.description,
        statusName : $scope.applicationsDetails.statusName
      };
      debugger;
      applications.getApplications().update({id:$scope.applicationsDetails.id}, modelSchema, function(response){
        Notification.success("success");
      }, function(response){
        Notification.error("error");
      });
    }
```

****NOTE : this works in safari.
so, how to stop chrome to send preflight for rest calls. Can we change anything in the header config?**
**

Comment: From what your describe, your issue is CORS. Meaning you are in 1 domain and trying to access information from another domain. If you include the language you are using and if you have access to the source code for the other domain I can help you further

Comment: Fix the server error? Based on the very limited information you have provided, that is all I can suggest. A 500 error is generated by the server, not the browser, so either your proxy is set up differently in Safari so it points to a different server, or there is something on the server causing the error based on the request from safari. You will need to [edit] the question to provide more details

Comment: I guess, your proxy settings is the culprit. Compare proxy settings between the browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The better solution is modify your backend (server): it's needing the CORS headers. If your backend is in PHP, here is the solution:
http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html

If you need a temporary solution, you can install this extension for chrome:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unxss/cbjmpjkhiafmdnjnigdbelcnbihgpmge
But your app only work when this extension is installed.

Regards...